# Display content on click from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabular

I have a table which is 9 x 9 with each cell having a different option.

Is it possible to do this:

When one of the cells text is clicked, everything relating to that is shown under that cell.

For example the cell title is advertising and when its clicked it shows links to different advertisers.

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: Include what you have tried, where you got stuck and what your desired outcome was, otherwise this question will get heavily downvoted and clsoed. And your tags are inaccurate.

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: Open your text editor/IDE and start coding: `/* TO DO :: Hire a developer! */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this http://fiddle.jshell.net/QsWkB/
Hope that helps.

Comment: It is always better to post the code in the answer. SO doesn't entertain link only answers because they will be of no use if the link becomes inactive for whatever reason.

Comment: That it ! but how would i make it so if one is open and another is clicked on it will be open.

Comment: @Harry Understood! Will do that from now on.

Comment: @StefanLazic I don't understand your question.

Comment: When a cell is clicked the content is shown . But when another is clicked the original remains open. How would I stop this from happening

Comment: By hiding all the .cell-content DIV's before showing the one you clicked on `$(document).on('click', 'td', function(){
   $('div.cell-content').hide();
   $(this).find('div.cell-content').toggle(); 
});` http://fiddle.jshell.net/QsWkB/1/

Comment: @Kyra Iv just coppied the code into a blank page and none of the drop downs work

Answer (score 0):

You can put a div containing related information and keep its display as none. On click of that particular test, just use toggle() for that corresponding div.

Comment: do you have a example could use?